# Python: clickable grid

Tags: python, grid, click

I'm pretty new to Python, and I've got a question about a sort of grid you can click. I want to create a grid of either images or simply a letter would even work. When clicked, the image or letter changes. For instance, if one clicked on the letter O, it would switch to X (and vice versa). If there's also a way to do this with like black & white images, that would be cool, though optional. Pretty much any advice here would be helpful. If there's no way I can do this in Python, where could I do it?

Comment: Use a graphics library such as [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html).

Comment: I understand that you can make a button that can do some actions with Tkinter, but how can I just make a button that turns from one color to another when clicked? Then, from that, how do I replicate that button to make a grid of them? I'm sorry if I come across as novice, but I just need help understanding this.

Comment: This is a separate question, and is more specific than the very broad question here. I'd recommend posting that separately.